# Best solution: add or addu

Tags: assembly, addition, mips, memory-address

What is the best solution for the translation of the following C code into MIPS assembly?

```
x = A[i];
```

*Note that `x ⇨ $t0`, `A[] ⇨ $s0`, `i ⇨ $s1`.*

With `add`:

```
sll $t0, $s1, 2
add $t0, $t0, $s0
```

or with `addu`:

```
sll $t0, $s1, 2
addu $t0, $t0, $s0
```

I know the [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16660298/3185964) between `add` and `addu`, but I not understand when to use one or the other.

Comment: If you understand the difference then you should understand when to use each. Do you want a trap on overflow or not?

Comment: I don't know. On what basis I must choose if I want a trap or not?

Comment: If you need to ask if you need an overflow trap, you do not need an overflow trap.

Answer (score 3):

C code won't throw an exception on integer overflow. So assembly shouldn't, either. Use `addu`.

Answer (score 0):

`add` in MIPS throws an exception on *signed* overflow.
Let's assume you want to index into a large array, and the array crosses between `(signed)INTPTR_MAX` and `(signed)INTPTR_MIN`. If you use `add`, this will throw an exception, although you may have been well within the array bounds.
What you are more likely to need to care for in array indexing is *unsigned* overflow, crossing from `(unsigned)UINTPTR_MAX` to `zero`, but MIPS doesn't help you there, AFAIK.