# I am trying to write a simple MIPS program that will add hexadecimal numbers, but I keep getting an error

Tags: mips32

I a writing a simple MIPS code to add two hexadecimal values and store the results in a register.  I am new to MIPS so I am having trouble finding the fix to an error message I have.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
.text
    .globl main
main:   add $t2,$t0,$t1 # add contents of $t0 and $t1, and store result in $t2

    li $v0,10       # terminate execution
    syscall
```

the error message:

> Error in C:\Users\smpan\OneDrive\Desktop\Computer\Computer Lab 2\Exercise4_3.asm line 4: Runtime exception at 0x00400000: arithmetic overflow

My goal for the program is to try and verify my hexadecimal addition is correct.  I am adding `0x7FAA3278` and `0x6024CD12`.  The program should store the result `0xDFCEFF8A` is the registered `$t2`.
Line 14 is the line that contains `main:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of that addition is too big to fit in a signed 32 bit value, and the CPU is telling you exactly that.

If you're expecting an unsigned result, or are happy with a negative result from adding two positive numbers, there's an 'add unsigned' instruction.

See here:

[Difference between add and addu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16634110/difference-between-add-and-addu)

Comment: Oh got it, thank you.  I figured I was using the wrong type of add